# How can i identify the delimiters of my sample logs and parse it?

Tags: vb6

I have this logs and i want to identify the delimiters of the logs and parse it. someone please help me.. i am a beginner in vb6.

[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/1.9.12;FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552};FBLC/en_GB;FBCR/GLOBE;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/GT-P3100;FBSV/4.0.4;]
[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/1.9.12;FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552};FBLC/en_GB;FBCR/GLOBE;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/GT-P3100;FBSV/4.0.4;]
Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)
Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)
Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)
[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/1.9.12;FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552};FBLC/en_GB;FBCR/GLOBE;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/GT-P3100;FBSV/4.0.4;]
Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)
Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)
AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10B329 (iPad; U; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X; en_us)
AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10B329 (iPad; U; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X; en_us)
AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10B329 (iPad; U; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X; en_us)
AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10B329 (iPad; U; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X; en_us)
[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/1.9.12;FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552};FBLC/en_GB;FBCR/GLOBE;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/GT-P3100;FBSV/4.0.4;]
[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/1.9.12;FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552};FBLC/en_GB;FBCR/GLOBE;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/GT-P3100;FBSV/4.0.4;]

Comment: Try looking for the natural boundaries with, for instance the `[]`s, `{}`s, `;`s and `/`s.  A good idea is to try breaking the file down into segments (i.e. break the line at particular points, for instance after a `]`).  It does depend, though, if the file format is available on line.  Where is the log from?

Comment: can you give me a code example for that? i'm using visual basic 6.. should i array it? it came from the user agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually, there seem to be 2 delimiters: `/` and `;`

The records seem to be encapsulated in `[` abd `]`, although not all of them (notice how text that begins with `Android` and `AppleCoreMedia` is not encapsulated.

The main delimiter seems to be `;` and `/` being the secondary. So, if you take a single record `[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/1.9.12;FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552};FBLC/en_GB;FBCR/GLOBE;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/GT-P3100;FBSV/4.0.4;]` it would split first by `;` into

```
FBAN/FB4A
FBAV/1.9.12
FBDM/{density=1.0,width=1024,height=552}
FBLC/en_GB
FBCR/GLOBE
FBPN/com.facebook.katana
FBDV/GT-P3100
FBSV/4.0.4
```

Then, split those pairs by `/` and you get a list of parameters with values. Looking through those parameters, I can even guess some of its functionality: `FBDM` - Dimensions, `FBLC` - Language Code. Also, please not that `FBDM` has a value that is encapsulated by a pair of `{` `}` and is comma delimited

The whole record is weird because from what you posted, first 2 records are fine (encapsulated by `[...]`) then you get 3 records that are duplicated and are not encapsulated: `Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)`, then you have a single good record, and then 2 weird records `Android/1.0 (GT-S5830 GINGERBREAD)` followed by 4 weird records `AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10B329` and finally ending with 2 normal records (encapsulated by `[...]`).

The 'weird" records that are not encapsulated by `[...]` seem to also be delimited, but they are delimited by `/` (with some records also being sub-delimited by `;`)

I hope this analysis helps.